# Accessing a singleton service within new instances of a class

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a .net console application where i need to access a service (ServiceBusClient) within all new instances of a 'Server' class.  The code below works.  My question is, am i doing this the best way? is it ok to pass the service as a parameter when instantiating a new class?

Thanks

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{       
    services.AddSingleton(x => new ServiceBusClient(Configuration.GetValue<string>(key: "ServiceBus:ConnectionString")));
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
public void Main(string[] args)
{
    var app = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
    var myService = app.Services.GetService<ServiceBusClient>();
    Thread t = new Thread(delegate ()
    {
       Server myserver = new Server("192.168.0.151", 6001, myService);
    });
    t.Start();
    app.Run();
}
```

**Server.cs**

```
class Server 
{
   private readonly ServiceBusClient _serviceBusClient;

   public Server(string ip, int port, ServiceBusClient serviceBusClient)
   {
     _serviceBusClient = serviceBusClient;
   }
}
```

Comment: `Thread t = new Thread(delegate ()` <-- **Don't do this**: there honestly is no legitimate reason to use the `new Thread` constructor anymore in C#/.NET.

Comment: The `GetService<T>` extension-method _can_ return `null` if a service isn't registered - instead you should use the `GetRequiredService<T>` extension-method instead, which guarantees it will return a service implementation or throw - which is better for this situation.

Comment: Use the options pattern and pass your IP and port as part of a DI options service. Then you can register the server as a DI service too and request an entire server from DI rather than constructing it yourself. It has a few benefits, 1) you can configure the IP and Port externally without a recompile. 2) You have less configuration and code. 3) You can control the usage of the server more granularly.

Comment: @Dai No there definitely are usage scenarios, a thread was recommended by David Folwer to be used over a task for long running operations when the workload will block the thread in ASP NET Core.

https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#avoid-using-taskrun-for-long-running-work-that-blocks-the-thread

Comment: @KieranDevlin Wow, dang - thanks - this is news to me - but I still can't shake the feeling that using `new Thread(...).Start()` feels _dangerous_ somehow...

Comment: Thanks guys, i'll research these points and implement

Comment: @KieranDevlin Note that D.F.'s example sets `Thread.IsBackground` to `true` while OP's code does not. Also, all the thread in OP's code does is instanciate a `Server` object. It isn't blocking nor looping otherwise (though I assume, that has been left out?). So, as-is, all the Thread does is creating and immediatly after that abandoning a `Server`, leaving it eligable to GC. So if there is a long running operation involved, it may have been a better idea to use a Thread _inside_ the `Server` class?

Comment: @Fildor note that I didn't say it was for OP's use case, I was addressing the claim " there honestly is no legitimate reason to use the new Thread constructor anymore in C#/.NET"

Comment: @KieranDevlin That is true, yes. Should have addressed OP not you.

Comment: Each instance of Server opens a socket connection for 1 hour

Comment: I would suggest to use `Task` instead of spawning a new thread manually. Let's delegate the hard thread management work to the framework. You can also spawn a task with the `LongRunning` option.